# Present perfect continuous

Tags: difference

I’ve been thinking about the subtle differences in these three sentences

> 1-I’ve been reading books for years
>   2-I’ve been reading a lot of books for years
>   3-I’ve been reading five books for years

From what I understand

The first sentence is the most common one and it means that I’ve read books and I still read books.
Basically you finish one and move to the next.

The second isn’t common and it can also mean that , say lot is 100 books 
So you’ve been reading 100 books together and you still haven’t finished any of them?
Or I’ve just finished all of them

The last one means that I’ve been reading five books and still haven’t finished them
Or I’ve just finished all of them

Is my understanding correct here?
My brain hurts after thinking of all of those interpretations.

Comment: Yes, you are interpreting these correctly.

Comment: The third one is not very likely, is it?

Comment: No it’s just for the sake of the question

Comment: I’ve got some questions though is the second one common or not ? Does it sound natural and would a native use it?

Comment: Yes, it's fine. I've been doing x for many years. is very common.